# How to make .exe in silent mode using Installed shiled 10.5

Tags: installation, installshield

i need to make .exe in silent mode. No need to display any dialogs(Including progress bar dialog also). Just click the exe and all the files should be installed without displaying any dialog.

Comment: Are you producing some virus! I think an installation file should get confirmation from the user and should inform the user for what is happening. BUT for this purpose you need another program or wrapper to run the main setup in silent mode. Tell me if you need more details!

Answer (score 1):

it depends if your project is MSI or InstallScript.
http://unattended.sourceforge.net/installers.php

**if MSI then:**

When launching the MSI package from the command line you can use multiple "msiexec.exe" parameters which affect the user interface:

```
full UI: /qf (this is the default parameter used by the package)
reduced UI: /qr (the user interface does not show any wizard dialogs)
basic UI: /qb, /passive (only a progress bar will be showed during the installation)
no UI: /qn, /quiet (no UI will be showed during the installation)
```

**else if InstallScript then:**

The Silent Install options for InstallShield installer
/s  Silent mode. For an InstallScript project, the command Setup.exe /s runs the installation in silent mode, by default based on the responses contained in a response file called Setup.iss in the same directory.

/r  Record mode. In order to run an InstallScript project installation program in silent mode, you must first run Setup.exe with the /r option to generate a response file, which stores information about the data entered and options selected by the user at run time. Running an InstallScript installation program with the command Setup.exe /r displays all the run-time dialogs, and stores the data in a file called Setup.iss, created inside the system’s Windows folder. response file name and location, use the /f1 option, described below.

/f1     Specify alternative response file name and path Using the /f1 option enables you to specify where the response file is (or where it should be created) and what its name is, as in Setup.exe /s /f1"C:\Temp\Setup.iss". Specify an absolute path; using a relative path gives unpredictable results. The /f1 option is available both when creating a response file (with the /r option) and when using a response file (with the /s option)

/f2     Specify alternative log file name and path When running an InstallScript installation in silent mode (using the /s option), the log file Setup.log is by default created in the same directory and with the same name (except for the extension) as the response file. The /f2 option enables you to specify an alternative log file location and file name, as in Setup.exe /s /f2"C:\Setup.log". Specify an absolute path; using a relative path gives unpredictable results.